# Creating three tables with header

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, three.js

I'm trying to cycle through a table and create three tables of clickable divs with a header for each (ideally with a separate class to make them look different). I'm trying to use a while loop with three if statements but the headers are not displaying properly. All three still show up as normal divs instead of with different classes but the first one is covered with a second copy of the third column header with the correct header and the second header is covered with a second copy of the first header, again with the correct class.

JS Snippet

```
var table = [


        "Column Title", "#", 2,2,
        "Column Item", "website.com", 1, 3,
        "Column Item 2", "website2.com", 2, 3,
        // Etc.
];
var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;

var objects = [];
var targets = { table: [], sphere: [], helix: [], grid: [] };

init();
animate();

function init() {

    for ( var i = 0; i < table.length; i += 4 ) {

        if(i === 0){
                var courtsTitle = document.createElement('div');
                courtsTitle.className = 'listTitle';
                courtsTitle.innerHTML = "<p>Column Title</p>";

                var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( courtsTitle );
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                scene.add( object );

                objects.push( object );


                var object = new THREE.Object3D();
                object.position.x = ( 6 * 480 ) - 2900;
                object.position.y = - ( 2 * 340 ) + 1550;

                targets.table.push( object );
            }
            if(i === 14){
                var departmentsTitle = document.createElement('div');
                departmentsTitle.className = 'listTitle';
                departmentsTitle.innerHTML = "<p>Column Title2</p>";

                var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( departmentsTitle );
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                scene.add( object );

                objects.push( object );


                var object = new THREE.Object3D();
                object.position.x = ( 10 * 480 ) - 2900;
                object.position.y = - ( 2 * 340 ) + 1550;

                targets.table.push( object );
            }

            if(i === 28){
                var servicesTitle = document.createElement('div');
                servicesTitle.className = 'listTitle';
                servicesTitle.innerHTML = "<p>Column Title3</p>";

                var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( servicesTitle );
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                scene.add( object );

                objects.push( object );

                //

                var object = new THREE.Object3D();
                object.position.x = ( 2 * 480 ) - 2900;
                object.position.y = - ( 2 * 340 ) + 1550;

                targets.table.push( object );
            } else {
                var department = document.createElement('a');
                department.className = 'department';
                department.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
                department.setAttribute('href', table[i + 1]);
                department.setAttribute('target', "_blank");

                var link = document.createElement('div');
                link.className = 'link';
                link.innerHTML = table[i];
                department.appendChild(link);

                /*Random Starting point*/
                var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( department );
                object.position.x = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.y = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                object.position.z = Math.random() * 4000 - 2000;
                scene.add( object );

                objects.push( object );


                /*Final position*/
                var object = new THREE.Object3D();
                object.position.x = ( table[ i + 2 ] * 480 ) - 2900;
                object.position.y = - ( table[ i + 3 ] * 340 ) + 1550;

                targets.table.push( object );
            } 

}
```

Comment: i don't understand much your first array, can you link a jsfiddle or codepen or describe one full table in this array so we can reproduce your problem ?  Note that :

1. you would may use arrays of arrays so the increment be 1 and simplify the for-loop ?

2. there is no while-loop

Comment: Sorry I can't right now, but basically the 1st item is the title, 2nd is a url or #, 3rd is for x-location, 4th is for y-location - those 4 all go together. Then the 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, are for the next item and etc. And yes, array of arrays sounds like a good idea. Originally this array was much simpler and it just kept growing lol. Thanks!